# SSL handshake with WSO2 ESB and client application

Tags: ssl, handshake, ca, wso2-esb

In our WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 we had setup CA certificate (root, intermediate and the final) in new JKS and had configured our carbon, axis2 and catalina xmls.

Now we want the client application to hit our ESB on https with SSL, can you let us know what details do we need to share to our client application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Client should have the public key of the server.

Comment: can you suggest how to generate public key from JKS ? or CA will give the public key

Comment: You can simply Download the public key from your browser. Access the management console URL through a browser. Now close to he URL there should be a green padlock icon click on that and download the certificate.

Comment: from the browser URL we right clicked on the padlock details-> view certificate -> Details (show All)-> copy to File option (.cer),.cer is saved to local drive ,  is this correct approach

Comment: Yes that should do.